# writing data inside a structure via pointer

Tags: c, struct, malloc, scanf

I've defined a struct and allocated the necessary space in the memory via malloc, I want to write data inside the struct, can someone help me on the syntax of the scanf function in this case?

I thought that when I created a malloc the variable has inside the address so I thought that I could navigate the struct by moving trough the memory
evidently I was wrong;

```
struct airplanesType
{
    char TractionType[15];
    int superficeAlare;
    int peso;
    int coefficenteDiCarico;
    int rendimento;
    int cordaMedia;
    int distanzaCPCG;
    int distanzaCGCoda;
    int distanzaDragTraction;
    int MaxTraction;
    int ClMax;
    int CDclmax;
};

typedef struct airplanesType aereo;
```

the struct;

```
    aereo *cesna= malloc(sizeof(aereo));
```

how I call the the malloc

Comment: Use the member access operator `->` to assign values to the `struct` members. (e.g., `cesna->superficeAlare = 1;` I don't fully understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use objects not types in `sizeof` when possible.

```
aereo *cesna= malloc(sizeof(*cesna));
```

2. `->` dereferences the struct pointer.

> can someone help me on the syntax of the scanf function in this case?

```
scanf("%d", &cesna -> cordaMedia);
```

you can also use `(*cesna).cordaMedia`

```
scanf("%d", &(*cesna).cordaMedia);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to write data inside the struct, can someone help me on the
> syntax of the scanf function in this case?

Like was previously mentioned, whenever you are working with structs, use the `.` or `->` operators to access the fields within the struct directly. You *can* work with direct memory manipulation, but doing that is much, much harder, leads to much messier code, and is very prone to errors.

In this particular case you can access the `peso` field like any other variable by using `cesna->peso`, and the `clMax` field by using `cesna->clMax`.

However...

> scanf function

Whomever taught you about this function is doing you a great disservice. Not only is this function borderline obsolete, unless you know exactly what to do with `scanf`, chances are big you will introduce memory leaks in your code. See this question for further info.

[Disadvantages of scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf)

It is widely recommended that you either look into the `fgets()` system call or look up how to send arguments to the program via command line and the `argc` + `argv` functions. Both are useful tools in your arsenal. More on this topic:

https://c-for-dummies.com/blog/?p=3379

http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html

Argc+Argv does require you to start the program from command line but is super useful to integrate with other tools in the Linux world.

To be clear, `scanf` is nice to teach beginners so they do not need to be concerned about things like string-to-numbers conversions and buffer overflows just to write a program that asks and displays your age, but as soon as you learn what a string is and how to use it in C... You *should* drop `scanf`, for your own sanity.